# Build with makefile on windows 10

Tags: c++, makefile

I have been trying to build the project source code the last 5 days.

link:https://github.com/shumatech/BOSSA

I have installed make,  mingw and wxwidgets using chocolatey when I run make i get this error:

```
\Desktop\BOSSA-1.9.1>make
make: wx-config: No such file or directory
make: wx-config: No such file or directory
make: git: No such file or directory
CPP BOSSA src/BossaForm.cpp
In file included from src/BossaForm.cpp:8:
src/BossaForm.h:11:10: fatal error: wx/artprov.h: No such file or directory
   11 | #include <wx/artprov.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:259: obj/BossaForm.o] Error 1
```

I know this workflow document exits but I don't understand how to follow those instructions
https://github.com/kiibohd/BOSSA/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml#L51

I have been trying really hard with this any help is appreciated!

Comment: Attempting to shoehorn Linux software, like gcc, make, and other libraries you mentioned into an alien operating system that they weren't designed for is something that even experienced developers will struggle with, not to mention those who are new to C++. Most of the time it takes much less time to simply install Linux from scratch, and get a fully working, fully configured, modern C++ compiler out of the box. It took me just an hour and a half, last time, much less than the time you've been struggling with. And now I'd just buy a Lenovo laptop with preloaded Linux. 0 minutes to do this.

Comment: From the [Makefile](https://github.com/shumatech/BOSSA/blob/master/Makefile#L36) it seems Mingw isn't an alien target for this project. But the [workflow](https://github.com/kiibohd/BOSSA/actions/workflows/build.yml) you've referred to never built successfully.

Comment: Ok makes sense I managed to build it using Mac much faster, but I need a windows .exe. I have been trying read into cross compile aswell but I can't seem to solve that either. You don't happen to know any tips on how to do that? Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: Yeah when I installed wxmac on my mac that solved the same error message that I now recieve on windows, maybe I have installed it wrong but it says it's installed according to choco

Comment: If you just need to use BOSSA, you could also have a Linux VM on your windows PC and just delegate the USB port to the VM so that you can flash your code to the controller.